# Sync is not available in Microsoft Edge with AAD Account

Tags: microsoft-edge

The new Microsoft Edge is unfortunately not always helpful in terms of error information.

[image]

For my work account (which is a O365 with AAD account, I'm the owner) Edge says

> Sync isn't available for this account

Unfortunately there is no indication why Sync is not available.
With my Microsoft accounts this works fine; only work accounts refuse to sync - and no hint or help at all.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the account configuration options. From [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-enterprise-sync#configuration-options-for-microsoft-edge-sync), you can see that:

> The following configuration options are available for enabling Microsoft Edge sync:
>
> - Azure Information Protection (AIP)
> - AAD Enterprise State Roaming (ESR)
>
> If both AIP and ESR are disabled, users will see an error message indicating that sync is not available for their account.

You could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/enterprise-state-roaming-enable) about how to enable Enterprise State Roaming in Azure Active Directory.

And currently Microsoft Edge sync for Azure Active Directory (AAD) accounts is only available for the following subscriptions:

> - AAD Premium (P1 and P2)
> - Office 365 E3 and above
> - Azure Information Protection (P1& P2)
> - All EDU subscriptions (O365 A1 or above, M365 A1 or above, or AIP P1 or P2 for Students or Faculty)